# Hierarchical dirichlet process results

Tags: data-mining, data-cleaning, unsupervised-learning, topic-model, dirichlet

I am thinking about using hierarchical dirichlet process to model a patent dataset. I've seen that HDP uses a base distribution and assumes that every topic comes from that base distribution.

The problem is: first I'm wondering what are the main results from the HDP procedure (in the case of LDA we obtain two matrices that we can use to construct word clouds and graphs but in this case I'm not sure about the results) and what is the exact procedure?

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR** Ist just a bayesian varianat that generalises LDA.

See [here](http://www.gatsby.ucl.ac.uk/%7Eywteh/research/npbayes/jasa2006.pdf)

Basically in the bayesian Setting you dont Need the params, but you can infer them from the data. Using the same dirichlet generative process logic you can **cluster grouped data**.